# Помогите создать кнопку с треугольником при клике на нее

Tags: html, css, button

Всем привет! Помогите создать кнопку с треугольником при клике на нее. Вот такое: http://joxi.ru/823vVv3UJq67wm (при клике на кнопку - у нее появляется доп. элемент треугольник)

Answer (score 0):

Его можно создать через псевдо-элемент `before`. Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/msuwev18/9/).

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ

```js
// Просто для визуализации

$('.menu a').on('click',function(){
  $('.menu a.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: relative; /* Обязательно */
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

/* Создаём треугольник при помощи псевдо-элемента */
.menu a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 8px solid transparent; /* Ширина уголка a=8, высота будет a/2 */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
}

.menu a:hover, .menu a.active {
  background: #1cde40;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Чтобы стрелка смотрела вниз, нужно цвет определить для верхнего бордюра. Чтобы вверх - вниз, влево - для правого и т.д. */
.menu a.active::after {
  border-top-color: #1cde40;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <a class="active" href="#">Index 1</a>
  <a href="#">Index 2</a>
  <a href="#">Index 3</a>
  <a href="#">Index 4</a>
  <a href="#">Index 5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!